# Can I store and retrieve .kml file from database sqlite

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I'm using osmnavigator, and I'm trying to retrieve raw kml from the sqlite but couldn't find any solution. Can I store the filename only and retrieve on parsekmlstream?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get an InputStream on what you want to read, then you should be able to use KmlDocument method:

```
public boolean parseKMLStream(InputStream stream, ZipFile kmzContainer)
```

(just pass null for the kmzContainer param)